# Manifest Merger failed with multiple errors in Android Studio for react native

Tags: android, react-native

Manifest Merger failed with multiple errors in Android Studio.
->Error: android: exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android: exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. SVBasketball.app main manifest (this file)

Comment: Can you tell us what you were trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to add a SDK in my react native project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the message have stated, property `android:exported` must be defined for an component that has an intent filter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>
    <application>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```